# Adjust section numbering in table of contects

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, appendices

I would like to adjust the section NUMBERING in the table of contents. I would prefer to name my appendices "Appendix 1.B Some additional Figures" in the document and A.1.B......Some additional Figures in the TOC. Where 1 is the chapter, and b is the appendix number. This example would indicate the second appendix

In reality my document contains multiple chapters that can contain appendices and my document as a whole will have appendices too. Therefore I prefer the \renewcommand solution within chapters.

For clarity, I rename the last sections to Appendix ... using the \renewcommand on \thesection. I don't actually add Appendices in the Latex-sense of the word

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Test Chapter One}

\section{Test Section One}
\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection A}
\subsection{Test Subsection B}

\setcounter{table}{0}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{chapter}.\Alph{section}.\arabic{table}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\Alph{section}.\arabic{figure}}
\setcounter{equation}{0}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\Alph{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{Appendix \arabic{chapter}.\Alph{section}}
\section{Test Section One}
\section{Test Section One}
\subsection{Test Subsection A}
\subsection{Test Subsection B}
\end{document}
```

MWE in overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/13672924fhvbftbbvpyy#/52883524/

Comment: What is the `2` in `2.B` referring  to then? The chapter number? How do you use the appendices in a chapter? As it stands, your document has no appendix yet.

Comment: That was just a random example> Chapter 2. I changed it and hope I made it more clear